# How to combine Caliburn.Micro.Logging with Ninject.Logging & log4net

Tags: c#, mvvm, ninject, log4net, caliburn.micro

I'm currently trying to combine the logging interfaces of Caliburn.Micro and Ninject with log4net. Each framework provides it's own logging façade, but they don't seem to work nicely together.

Here's a shortened version of my Caliburn bootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase {

    private IKernel _kernel;
    private ILogger _logger;

    protected override void Configure() {

        Log4NetConfigurator.Configure();
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new INinjectModule[] { new Log4NetModule(); });

        var logFactory = _kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>();
        _logger = loggerFactory.GetLogger("Startup");

        // what do here?
        // LogManager.GetLog = type = _logger?? (LogManager expects ILog, not ILogger..)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that implements Caliburn.Micro's logging interface and delegates calls to a log4net logger.

Alternatively, you can use a solution that has [already been created](http://buksbaum.us/2011/07/06/introducing-caliburn-micro-logging-log4net/), and which is [available via NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro.Logging.log4net/1.5.0).